# HTTPS redirect enabling users from logging in on first attempt

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My hosting company created a redirect for me to allow the https to appear in the browser on every page and added it into my .htaccess file. That works great and has made every page reflect the https. However, when a user attempts to login on the first try it redirects them back to the index page. Then if the user goes back to login again they are successful.

This is what is in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This is my redirect in my login page..

```
$remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('indexSignedIn.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = "The information you entered did not match our records.";
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
```

How can I enable to .htaccess file or change my redirect in my login page to allow users to successfully login on their first attempt?

Comment: I don't believe that has anything to do with your .htaccess redirect. All it does is redirect to https protocol. It's mostly like your code and a session issue.

Comment: @PanamaJack There was never an issue with my code until the .htaccess file was added. It work flawlessly before.

Comment: You should start debugging to see where the issue is. Start with your PHP redirects after a successful login.

Comment: @PanamaJack The issue is only present when I go to my site and the https redirect takes place. ie: When I go to the site the browser displays https://example.com. If I then go to the login page and try to login, it fails. If I go to the webpage and first click my 'Home' button (the browser then displays https://example/index.php and then proceed to login, it allows me.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. See what's making it fail. See how far into the login process it's getting. Is this custom? a CMS? or what? Is there something that needs to be turned on to work with https?

Comment: @PanamaJack It's a login system made by phpacademy. I customized it some though. It gets as far to bring up the Google Chrome 'Remember Password' prompt.

Comment: Open up chrome dev tools and make sure you're not seeing some errors in the console or redirect issues. when on that page

Comment: @PanamaJack I'm not sure if I'm using the console correctly, but the only thing I am seeing is an error with a picture after it redirects me back to the index.php page